# package "fdapace" (R) - How to access the principal components of the functional principal component analysis

Tags: r, functional-programming, time-series, data-mining, pca

After applying the FPCA() function of the "fdapace" package on a dataset, the function returns a FPCA object with various values and fields. Unfortunately I don't know which of those fields contain the Principal components and how to access them or plot them. I know that there is a documentation for the package but as a beginner it doesn't really help me(no criticism intended). You can find the documentation here: [fdapace.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdapace/fdapace.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The estimate of the functional principal components (FPCs) are saved in xiEst in the result list, a matrix each row of which is the FPCs for a subject in the data. You can make whatever plots you want with this information. See the following for an example.

> res = FPCA(Ly, Lt)
>
> res$xiEst # This is the matrix containing the FPC estimates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helps a lot. I suppose the first row of xiEst is the principal component, wich "contains" most of the variance of the dataset, am I right ?

Comment: Sure. Actually, the first functional principal components are shown in the first column instead of 1st row.

Comment: Actually I have a Problem understanding the whole meaning of the values in the xiEst matrix. I have openend a new question about it. Maybe you can take a look at it. Any help is highly appreciated : [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243613/package-fdapace-r-create-a-functional-plot-of-the-first-principal-componen)

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the first eigenfunction:

```
workGrid = FPCAsparse$workGrid
phi1=FPCAsparse$phi[,1]
plot(workGrid,phi1)
```

Plotting the mean function:

```
mu=FPCAsparse$mu
workGrid = FPCAsparse$workGrid
plot(workGrid,mu)
```